# My seeder file is not working as expected in mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm learning full stack development and Im having some trouble with my seeder file. I have a 'products' seeder file which is an array of objects, one of the properties is an empty array titled reviews. I have another 'reviews' seeder file which is an array of objects as well but it also holds an ObjectId for each user, name and the actual review. I'm trying to add Reviews relationship to the Products Collection, but the Product collection still shows up with an empty array instead of the review objectIDs.

I'm following along to a course and i copy pasted contents of the exact course to make sure there was no typo, however, I still get a Product collection with empty array for the review property.

//Products seeder file code:

```
const products = [
  {
    name: 'Product1 Lenovo Comp1 Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 5,
    price: 100,
    category: 'Computers/Laptops/Lenovo',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 5,
    reviewsNumber: 5,
    reviews: [],
    attrs: [{ key: 'color', value: 'blue' }],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product2 Lenovo Comp2 Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 5,
    price: 100,
    category: 'Computers/Laptops/Lenovo',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 5,
    reviewsNumber: 5,
    reviews: [],
    attrs: [
      { key: 'color', value: 'black' },
      { key: 'RAM', value: '1 TB' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product3 Dell Comp Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 5,
    price: 100,
    category: 'Computers/Laptops/Dell',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 5,
    reviewsNumber: 5,
    reviews: [],
    attrs: [
      { key: 'color', value: 'black' },
      { key: 'RAM', value: '1 TB' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product4 Tablet Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 5,
    price: 100,
    category: 'Tablets',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 5,
    reviewsNumber: 5,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product5 Tablet Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 10,
    price: 200,
    category: 'Tablets',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 5,
    reviewsNumber: 6,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product6 Tablet Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 15,
    price: 300,
    category: 'Tablets',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 4,
    reviewsNumber: 7,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product7 Tablet Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 20,
    price: 400,
    category: 'Tablets',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 4,
    reviewsNumber: 8,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product8 Tablet Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 25,
    price: 500,
    category: 'Tablets',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 3,
    reviewsNumber: 9,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product9 Monitor Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 5,
    price: 100,
    category: 'Monitors',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 5,
    reviewsNumber: 5,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product10 Monitor Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 10,
    price: 200,
    category: 'Monitors',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 5,
    reviewsNumber: 6,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product11 Monitor Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 15,
    price: 300,
    category: 'Monitors',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 4,
    reviewsNumber: 7,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product12 Monitor Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 20,
    price: 400,
    category: 'Monitors',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 4,
    reviewsNumber: 8,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product13 Monitor Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 25,
    price: 500,
    category: 'Monitors',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 3,
    reviewsNumber: 9,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product14 Game Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 5,
    price: 100,
    category: 'Games',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 5,
    reviewsNumber: 5,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product15 Game Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 10,
    price: 200,
    category: 'Games',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 5,
    reviewsNumber: 6,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product16 Game Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 15,
    price: 300,
    category: 'Games',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 4,
    reviewsNumber: 7,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product17 Game Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 20,
    price: 400,
    category: 'Games',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 4,
    reviewsNumber: 8,
    reviews: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'Product18 Game Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    description:
      'Product Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    count: 25,
    price: 500,
    category: 'Games',
    images: [
      { path: '/images/monitors-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/games-category.png' },
      { path: '/images/tablets-category.png' },
    ],
    rating: 3,
    reviewsNumber: 9,
    reviews: [],
  },
];

module.exports = products;
```

/Reviews seeder file code:

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

const reviews = [
  {
    comment:
      'Review. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    rating: 5,
    user: { _id: ObjectId(), name: 'John Doe' },
  },
  {
    comment:
      'Review. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    rating: 5,
    user: { _id: ObjectId(), name: 'John Doe' },
  },
  {
    comment:
      'Review. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    rating: 5,
    user: { _id: ObjectId(), name: 'John Doe' },
  },
  {
    comment:
      'Review. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    rating: 4,
    user: { _id: ObjectId(), name: 'John Doe' },
  },
  {
    comment:
      'Review. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ipsa ducimus architecto explicabo id accusantium nihil exercitationem autem porro esse.',
    rating: 3,
    user: { _id: ObjectId(), name: 'John Doe' },
  },
];

module.exports = reviews;
```

//Seeder file code

```
const connectDB = require('../config/db');
connectDB();

const categoryData = require('./categories');
const productData = require('./products');
const reviewData = require('./reviews');

const Category = require('../models/CategoryModel');
const Product = require('../models/ProductModel');
const Review = require('../models/ReviewModel');

const importData = async () => {
  try {
    await Category.collection.dropIndexes();
    await Product.collection.dropIndexes();

    await Category.collection.deleteMany({});
    await Product.collection.deleteMany({});
    await Review.collection.deleteMany({});

    await Category.insertMany(categoryData);
    const reviews = await Review.insertMany(reviewData);
    const sampleProducts = productData.map((product) => {
      reviews.map((review) => {
        product.reviews.push(review._id);
      });
      return { ...product };
    });
    await Product.insertMany(sampleProducts);

    console.log('Seeder data proceeded successfully');
    process.exit();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while proccessing seeder data', error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
importData();
```

Finally this is what I get on my console:
(node:73661) [MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
**MongoDB connection SUCCESS PAL
Seeder data proceeded successfully**

Note: while there is no error on the console, if you check the attached image, you will see that the review array is empty.

and here is the image from mongoDB showing empty array:
[mongodb image of product collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjaYn.png)

and here is the image of the review array showing that it is not empty:
[mongodb image of review collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDFCu.png)

Thank you and I apologize if anything was done incorrectly, I'm still fairly new to coding.

Comment: Hi, this site discourages the use of imgs for important parts of a question. Read this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)

Answer (score 0):

this is fine. This is just a warning message that in mongoose 7 there is a syntax update is all. MongoDB connection SUCCESS PAL Seeder data proceeded successfully. You DB is ready to go. if you want to remove the warning you can prepare for the change by setting to false. switched back to false by default in Mongoose 7. Use mongoose.set('strictQuery', false); if you like. I would not worry about it tbh.

Comment: Actually the issue is with the review property in the 'Products' seeder file, it shows up as an empty array when it should have populated with objectIDs.

I also attached an image from mongoDB to my original post showing the issue